# Safe to create website heavily depending on Javascript and AJAX in 2011?

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is a bit theoretical but I am unable to find out what is the % of users with Javascript disabled on their computer.

We are creating massive second-hand car portal with focus on speed and user experience. Site as such will work just fine with Javascript disabled but for new car insertion and specialised search filters we demand JS and AJAX.

Is it safe to consider usage of Javascript to be safe these days with people running Facebook, Twitter, Myspace and enjoying JS/AJAX technology? Looking at our stats from other website most people have already converted to IE7 (from IE6) with IE8 growing up quickly, then Firefox 3.6/4.0, Chrome 10 and Safari. All these supporting Javascript by default.

You opinions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Site as such will work just fine with Javascript disabled but for new car insertion and specialised search filters we demand JS and AJAX.

For me that's the key thing right there. The basics of the site will work without JavaScript, but if you want to do things like list cars or do fancy search filters, you have to use JavaScript. To me, that's not a bad balance in 2011, no. Important that the site *work* (in terms of displaying information already held) without JavaScript, but it's fine to require JS for some features. Be sure to degrade nicely there, too, with a nice message telling them why they can't do those things and how to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

I think the percentage of people with javascript disabled nowadays is negligible. Most of those people will be javascript luddites who run NoScript/whatever and also have Flash and cookies disabled. And anyway, those people are technical enough to understand they must enable javascript for your site to work properly, and can turn it on if they need to. So you can safely ignore that crowd.

That said, it's still nice to downgrade gracefully to a non-AJAX version of the site if that is technically feasible and makes actual sense re: your business/target.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what parts you whant to be safe and how you implement your javascripts and ajax. If you manage all DB connections and important stuff like calculate prices and such,  in webservices and only show the actual result from this service then you have good protection atleast for your backend. Then you simply let the client scripts handle simpler calculations and GUI:s with action handling.

Comment: All the DB transactions and user input checks are running as webservices, so yes, it is safe from applications side. JS/AJAX really works for things like dynamically loading brands/models/motors and etc. without need to refresh site every single time.